# Windows Server version & WCF behaviour

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, tcp

How do you think can Windows Server version (I mean 2003 and 2008 Win Servers) affects on behaviour of .NET communication programs - programs which use classes from System.Net namespace, WCF services, WCF clients ? 
As far as I know network-related classes and libraries in .NET Framework 2.0 and later are independent from native Windows API and in theory must work identically in Win XP, 7, 2003, 2008

But is this fact really take place in real life situations?
Now we develop distributed system with WCF services, Windows Identity framework on .NET 3.5 and we have to write requirements for customer server computers, but in our environment we use only Win Server 2008, so could you advice can we allow our customer use older Windows version - for example 2003 server (customer use it) or this is too much risky?

I would be grateful if you share some of your experience in this field - pitfalls in change Windows version and it's compatibility with .NET applications!

Thank you!